# How to combine two column lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have

```
g = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
c = [[9], [8], [7], [6], [5], [4]]
```

And I need to get

```
t = [[1,9], [2,8], [3,7], [4,6], [5,5], [6,4]]
```

Please help me out here

Comment: And you didn't try anything yet. Did you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) here to combine the elements of the nested lists:

```
t = [a + b for a, b in zip(g, c)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> g = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
>>> c = [[9], [8], [7], [6], [5], [4]]
>>> [a + b for a, b in zip(g, c)]
[[1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 5], [6, 4]]
```

It can be made slightly more efficient by using the [iterative `zip()` function from Python 3 / `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.zip):

```
try:
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    pass

t = [a + b for a, b in zip(g, c)]
```

The `try..except` is only necessary if you want the code to work on both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: It is better to do a + b if there are more then one elements inside the nested list.

Comment: @seartun: agreed, that's a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without zip, using list comprehension:

```
>>> g = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
>>> c = [[9], [8], [7], [6], [5], [4]]
>>> result = [ [g[i][0], c[i][0]] for i in range(min([len(g), len(c)])) ]
>>> print(result)
[[1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 5], [6, 4]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are in Python 2.7 you can just use zip

```
g = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
c = [[9], [8], [7], [6], [5], [4]]
t = zip(g, c)
[([1], [9]), ([2], [8]), ([3], [7]), ([4], [6]), ([5], [5]), ([6], [4])]
```