# Combine lists from several columns into one nested list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
| col1     | col2      | col3     |
----------------------------------
[1,2,3,4] | [1,2,3,4] | [1,2,3,4]
```

I also have this function:

```
def joiner(col1,col2,col3):
    snip = []
    snip.append(col1)
    snip.append(col2)
    snip.append(col3)
    return snip
```

I want to call this on each of the columns and assign it to a new column.

My end goal would be something like this:

```
| col1     | col2      | col3     | col4
------------------------------------------------------------------
[1,2,3,4] | [1,2,3,4] | [1,2,3,4] | [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652502/how-to-combine-two-column-lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `.apply` list on `axis=1`, it'll create lists for each rows

```py
>>> df['col4'] = df.apply(list, axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
           col1          col2          col3  col4
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
df['col'] = df.values.tolist()
```